# UISLider setting thumb/minimumTrack/maximumTrack tint color gets exception

Tags: iphone, ios, exception, uislider, tintcolor

According to developer.apple I should be able to set UISLider's property - thumbTintColor/minimumTrackTintColor/maximumTrackTintColor - reference http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

But setting any of these properties raises "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception.

I know there is a workaround for this by setting image properties. But I don't want to go that way. Is there anything I'm missing?

Please any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code from UICatalog project of developer.apple examples:

```
- (UISlider *)sliderCtl
{
    if (sliderCtl == nil) 
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(174.0, 12.0, 120.0, kSliderHeight);
        sliderCtl = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [sliderCtl addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        // in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color
        sliderCtl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // I just added this following line to test
        sliderCtl.thumbTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        sliderCtl.minimumValue = 0.0;
        sliderCtl.maximumValue = 100.0;
        sliderCtl.continuous = YES;
        sliderCtl.value = 50.0;

        // Add an accessibility label that describes the slider.
        [sliderCtl setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"StandardSlider", @"")];

        sliderCtl.tag = kViewTag;   // tag this view for later so we can remove it from recycled table cells
    }
    return sliderCtl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to do this on not iOS5 devices/simulators. The API you want to use are only available on iOS5.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've just tested it now. Its works fine when I choose iOS 5 simulators. But get exception with <iOS5. So I guess for <iOS5 I've to use workarounds. If there is any better way, please do notify.

Comment: Unless you bake your own you can't get this on ios 4. However you can use respondsToSelector to have universal code. They will just different between 4 an 5